# Format according to multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting, vba

I have the following conditional formats, and I am wondering if it is possible to join them together in one, so I don't need to add them all separately:

```
IF($A11&$D11=$W$14;AND($K11>$X$14;$K11<$Y$14))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$15;AND($K11>$X$15;$K11<$Y$15))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$16;AND($K11>$X$16;$K11<$Y$16))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$17;AND($K11>$X$17;$K11<$Y$17))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$18;AND($K11>$X$18;$K11<$Y$18))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$19;AND($K11>$X$19;$K11<$Y$19))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$20;AND($K11>$X$20;$K11<$Y$20))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$21;AND($K11>$X$21;$K11<$Y$21))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$22;AND($K11>$X$22;$K11<$Y$22))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$23;AND($K11>$X$23;$K11<$Y$23))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$24;AND($K11>$X$24;$K11<$Y$24))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$25;AND($K11>$X$25;$K11<$Y$25))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$26;AND($K11>$X$26;$K11<$Y$26))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$27;AND($K11>$X$27;$K11<$Y$27))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$28;AND($K11>$X$28;$K11<$Y$28))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$29;AND($K11>$X$29;$K11<$Y$29))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$30;AND($K11>$X$30;$K11<$Y$30))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$31;AND($K11>$X$31;$K11<$Y$31))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$32;AND($K11>$X$32;$K11<$Y$32))
IF($A11&$D11=$W$33;AND($K11>$X$33;$K11<$Y$33))
```

Green fill to be applied to $K$11:$K$344 within a Table:

[image: Example Picture]

If this can be done easily in VBA, that could do as well.

Comment: Applied to: $K$11:$K$344. Subject to color Green. the range is in a table

Comment: Is it normal that the first and last two are exactly the same? And are all of these becoming green if any one condition is satisfied?

Comment: Ah no, thanks, updated the description. If this can be done easely in VBA, that could do as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please select K11:K344 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(K11>=VLOOKUP(A11&D11,W$14:Y$344,2,0),K11<=VLOOKUP(A11&D11,W$14:Y$344,3,0))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green, OK, OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS($U$11:$U$33,A11,$V$11:$V$33,D11,$X$11:$X$33,"<"&K11,$Y$11:$Y$33,">"&K11)
```

The above does not need the concatenated Region and Site Type (thus more criteria can be added as needed), but if you already have it, you can shorten it a little bit:

```
=COUNTIFS($W$11:$W$33,A11&D11,$X$11:$X$33,"<"&K11,$Y$11:$Y$33,">"&K11)
```

The set up of the conditional formatting remains the same.

`COUNTIFS` will return a number above 0 (interpreted as true) if there any matches to the Region, Site Type, lower and upper bounds, otherwise will return 0.

Comment: Note: can be slower than VLOOKUP since it looks into the entire table range instead of stopping at first match, but is more flexible on the number of criteria columns.